# Text only Data Validation

Tags: excel, excel-formula, validation, vba

I know there was a similar question asked but I couldn't manipulate that code. What I need is Data validation that will make sure the user ONLY enters 2 characters and both of them have to be text. I keep running into trouble because the system allows when I type w1. Any help would be greatly appreciated

[image]

Data Validation only 2 characters long and both characters must be text

Comment: `both characters must be text` - only a-z and A-Z? or any characters except 0-9?

Comment: a-z it does not matter if it is uppercase or not when I run the macro it converts it the uppercase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know whether it is the best way, but try it:

```
=AND(LEN(A1)=2,LOWER(LEFT(A1,1))>="a",LOWER(LEFT(A1,1))<="z",LOWER(RIGHT(A1,1))>="a",RIGHT(LEFT(A1,1))<="z")
```